# Using the definition of the operator norm

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, vectors, normed-spaces

I am given the following problem:

> Using the definition $$\lVert L \rVert_{\text{op}}=\sup_{\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^d, \lVert \vec{u} \rVert=1}\lVert L\vec{u} \rVert$$ of the operator norm of a linear mapping $L:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^n$, find $\lVert M \rVert_{\text{op}}$ where $M:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $M(x,y)=x+y$
>
> **Hint:** Use the fact that a point $(x,y)$ on a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as $(x,y)=(\sin t,\cos t)$ with $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

I am really not sure where to start with this, any help would be great!

Comment: have you tried to use the given hint?

Comment: You have to find $\sup\{|x+y| : x,y\in\mathbb R,\,x^2+y^2 = 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the vectors of norm 1 are of the form $v = (\cos t, \sin t)$ with $t$ in $[0, 2\pi)$. You can then compute the norm $\|Mv\|$ of such a vector, and then find the supremum to get the norm of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

What the hint says amounts to say that a vector $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\lVert \vec{u} \lVert = 1$ has coordinates $(\sin t, \cos t)$ for $0 \leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi$.

Hence, 
$$\lVert M \rVert_{\text{op}} = \sup_{0 \leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi} \lvert \cos t + \sin t\lvert$$

This supremum can only occur at an absciss $t$ where the derivative of the function $f:\ t\mapsto \cos t + \sin t$ vanishes. We have $f'(t) = - \sin t + \cos t$. Hence, we have 
$$f'(t) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \cos t = \sin t \Longleftrightarrow t \equiv \frac{\pi}{4}[\pi]$$

Hence, $\lVert M \rVert_{\text{op}}= \cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \sqrt{2}$